# Django model.objects.all() queryset not displaying content - how to fix?

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I'm learning Django and trying to setup some dynamic pages. I've mapped url's to /restaurants and /restaurants/mexican however my html content block is not displaying anything from my queryset. Code below:

views.py

```
def restaurantListView(request):
    template_name = 'restaurants/restaurants_list.html'
    queryset = Restaurant.objects.all()
    context = {
        "objectList": queryset
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)

class RestaurantListView(ListView):
    queryset = Restaurant.objects.all()
    template_name = 'restaurants/restaurants_list.html'

class MexicanRestaurantListView(ListView):
    queryset = Restaurant.objects.filter(category__iexact='mexican')
    template_name = 'restaurants/restaurants_list.html'

class AsianFusionRestaurantListView(ListView):
    queryset = Restaurant.objects.filter(category__iexact='asian fusion')
    template_name = 'restaurants/restaurants_list.html'
```

urls.py

```
from restaurants.views import (
    restaurantListView, 
    RestaurantListView, 
    MexicanRestaurantListView, 
    AsianFusionRestaurantListView,
    )

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html')),
    path('restaurants/', RestaurantListView.as_view()),
    path('restaurants/mexican/', MexicanRestaurantListView.as_view()),
    path('restaurants/asian/', AsianFusionRestaurantListView.as_view()),
    path('about/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='about.html')),
    path('contact/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='contact.html')),
]
```

restaurants_list.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block head_title %} Restaurants || {{ block.super }} {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Restaurant List</h1>

<ul>
    {% for obj in objectList %}
        <li>{{ obj.name }} | {{ obj.location }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

I expected the items of Restaurant.objects.all() to be displayed in my content block on restaurants.html, but instead nothing is displaying. Same occurs for objects.filter() on the /restaurants/mexican route.

Comment: add what exact error shows

Comment: @ShafikurRahman 
I dont receive any errors. I get a HTTP 200 response when directing to /restaurants/, however the content doesn't display from content block in my .html file

Comment: so check first is 'mexican' category contents available or not.

Comment: Yes when I run the following in the python shell it displays the mexican category values:
queryset.filter(category__iexact='mexican').
It's not only the mexican category, even the /restaurants/ content isnt displaying

Comment: first try to check is data available with .all() in django shell

Comment: Here is my shell output:
qs = Restaurant.objects.all()
qs
<QuerySet [<Restaurant: Feedbag>, <Restaurant: El Toro's>, <Restaurant: Hungry Jacks>]>
So we can see there is data available.

If I use just the first function in views.py, that works perfectly, however it's only when I try to display the info above with classes that the data doesnt get displayed.

Could it be to do with the context of objectList only being defined in the function?

Comment: THis is not import correctly in urls.py `restaurantListView`

Answer (score 1):

The template variable should be `object_list`, not `objectList`.

(Note, you certainly don't need one view per restaurant type. Rather, have a view for RestaurantsByType and get the type as a URL parameter.)

Comment: Ah okay, I did not realize that object_list was built in and could not be changed.
Thanks for working that one out for me, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

'''
Just add one extra "_" in the  'category__iexact'
'''

```
class MexicanRestauratListView(ListView):
    queryset = RestaurantLocation.objects.filter(category__iexact='mexican')
    template_name = "restaurants/restaurantlocation_list.html"

class AsianFusionRestauratListView(ListView):
    queryset = RestaurantLocation.objects.filter(category__iexact='asian fusion')
    template_name = "restaurants/restaurantlocation_list.html"
```

Comment: You might want to work a bit on how you format your answer - for instance using code fences (```) and other such things. It can make your answers easier to read. Did you notice that this question is over a year old?